# create a blank table with no column

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Is it possible to create a table without any column? If YES then how can I do it in oracle.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You might want to add some code if you have some to make the question for clear for those who answer :)

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  What would a table without columns accomplish?

Comment: What would you like to do with the table after creating it?

Comment: it cannot be called a table if it doesn't have any column. Its is not possible

Comment: There is one dummy table, it is called `dual` but it has one column. Does it count?

Comment: As already pointed out, this makes no sense. However, in 12c you could possibly create a table with just one column and make that column "invisible" using `ALTER TABLE t MODIFY c INVISIBLE` (but I haven't tested this so don't know if it would be allowed or not) - of course, such a table would be useless.

Comment: I know that a table has minimum one column otherwise it can not be called as table.I just need to know that if i have one table and if i delete all the columns in it,then whether it gives me an error message or just allow me and oracle automatically create one unique column.

Comment: [It would be possible in PostgreSQL](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/03/17/creating-tables-dum-and-dee-in-postgresql/)

Answer (score 9):

1. Create table without columns:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE tab();
   ```

> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

2. Create with one column and try to drop it:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE tab(t INT);
   ALTER TABLE tab
   DROP COLUMN t;
   ```

> ORA-12983: cannot drop all columns in a table

The construct with no column does not have any sense. If you need table as placeholder use `DUAL` like:

```
SELECT 1 + 1 AS result
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Zero-column tables are supported in MS Access and ProgresSQL. This appears to be an implementation detail of Oracle, SQLite and other systems that do not support zero-column tables. One possible use-case for a zero-column table is to create the table once, then add columns as required. You'd have to do it differently in Oracle and SQLite but its not a crazy use-case.

Answer (score 4):

Creating an empty table then adding columns leads to cleaner code if you're driving SQL from (say) Java. Otherwise you have to treat the first column as special and incorporate it in the table creation statement.

Answer (score 3):

A table is a collection of columns and rows. You need at least one column.

Comment: Zero-column tables are supported in some database systems, like MS Access and ProgresSQL